# How to name a list of elements directly from the argument of the function using apply

Tags: r, list, return-value, named

I have a function with three arguments, each as a list. The values of these arguments are not fixed. They are outputs of another function applied to different datasets. I would like to pass a name for each output. My original function returns specific results of each dataset. Then, from the result, I can know what is the best model for me. So the easy way to do so is printing all the result with the name of the model. I can do that manually but it is very time consuming and sometimes leads me to make a mistake. Hence, I tried to write a function to make this task easy.

**I am thinking of using`paste` function, but do not know the correct way to do it.**

Since my function is long and very difficult, I provide a simple example.

```
myfun <- function(x){
    out <- list()
    out$x1 <- x^2
    out$x2 <- x^3
    out$x3 <- x^2+1
    return(out)
}

y1 <- 4
y2 <- 5
y3 <- 6


res1 <- myfun(y1)
res2 <- myfun(y2)
res3 <- myfun(y3)

myfun2 <- function(out1=list(), out2=list(), out3=list()){
    m <- length(out1)
    outfin <- lapply(1:m, function(i) c(out1[[i]], out2[[i]], out3[[i]]))
    return(outfin)
}
out1 <- list(res1$x1, res2$x1, res3$x1)
out2 <- list(res1$x2, res2$x2, res3$x2)
out3 <- list(res1$x3, res2$x3, res3$x3)

res.fin <- myfun2(out1, out2, out3)
```

Then I will get this:

```
> res.fin
[[1]]
[1] 16 64 17

[[2]]
[1]  25 125  26

[[3]]
[1]  36 216  37
```

**Expected output:**

I would like to have something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1]"x1:" 16 64 17

[[2]]
[1]"x2:" 25 125  26

[[3]]
[1] "x3:" 36 216  37
```

**Very important: In this example, each list has only 3 elements. However, sometimes, I need to work with an arbitrary number (non-fixed number) of elements, say `8` or `10`. So, I would like to use `lapply` to do that for me automatically inside my function.**

Comment: This is no different to creating any other named list. When you say the length is variable, do you have a vector of names `c('x', 'x^2', 'x^3', ...)` or else where do we get the names from? See `setNames`

Comment: You will never have a vector of `c("x1:", 16, 64, 17)`: vectors in R must be the same type, so your numbers would be coerced to strings. In R, naming the elements of a list would instead replace `[[1]]` with `x1`, allowing you to do `res.fin$x1` and/or `res.fin[["x1"]]`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I do not have a vector of the name because the number of elements in my list is not fixed. I tried to use paste function inside `lapply` so each time it pastes for me the model number and the values.

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much for your comment. No. I just need to paste a name with the output. Maybe I can use paste function but I do not know how to use it with `lapply`.

Comment: Use **`setNames`**

Comment: I've explained why you cannot get your expected output without changing the values from numbers to strings. *"I just need to paste a name with the output"* doesn't make a lot of sense given how R stores and does things. Why don't you just use `names(outfin) <- paste0("x", seq_len(outfin))` before returning it from your function?

Comment: Equivalently, `setNames(paste0("x", seq_len(outfin)), outfin)`

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comment. Because my function is estimation model and I need to have a specific output with specific names. Then, I would like to list all my tries models in one function and see who is the best for me. To do so, I need to give each of them a name to make it easy to me to know which model is the selected one.

Comment: @smci Actually, it's `setNames(outfin, paste0("x", seq_along(outfin)))`.

Comment: Right, @RuiBarradas ... and if you look at `setNames`, it's doing precisely what I suggested, so even better :-)

Comment: @RuiBarradas: yes, sorry, slip of the brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following will do what you want.

```
myfun2 <- function(out1=list(), out2=list(), out3=list()){
    m <- length(out1)
    outfin <- lapply(1:m, function(i) c(out1[[i]], out2[[i]], out3[[i]]))
    setNames(outfin, paste0("x", seq_along(outfin)))
}

res_list <- lapply(ls(pattern = "^res\\d+$"), get)

out1b <- unlist(lapply(res_list, `[`, 1), recursive = FALSE)
out2b <- unlist(lapply(res_list, `[`, 2), recursive = FALSE)
out3b <- unlist(lapply(res_list, `[`, 3), recursive = FALSE)

res.finb <- myfun2(out1b, out2b, out3b)
```

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.